# count Symbols in java

Tags: java, methods, symbols

I'm working with a program read a text file and then count the number of (upperCase, lowerCase, space ).My question is how can I count the rest of the text such as (digit, ". ' ()/ :;) together?

here is some of the code

```
for (int b = 0; b < crunchifyLine.length(); b++) {
    if (Character.isUpperCase(crunchifyLine.charAt(b))) {
        UppeLetter++;
    }
}

for (int b = 0; b < crunchifyLine.length(); b++) {
    if (Character.isLowerCase(crunchifyLine.charAt(b))) {
        LowerLetter++;
    }
}

for (int c = 0; c < crunchifyLine.length(); c++) {
    if (Character.isWhitespace(crunchifyLine.charAt(c))) {
        spaceNum++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe the question is about finding something like nextInt() maybe  a nextSymbol() to find symbols in a string, or the 2 ways to convert decimal to binary (code or method) so doesnt exactly needs to be a code writing request . I dont know the answer, but i dont believe it to be offtopic.

Answer (score 2):

Based on "some of the code" I'd change it to something more like:

```
for (int b = 0; b < crunchifyLine.length(); b++) {
    if (Character.isUpperCase(crunchifyLine.charAt(b))) {
        UppeLetter++; // [sic]
    } else if (Character.isLowerCase(crunchifyLine.charAt(b))) {
        LowerLetter++;
    } else if (Character.isWhitespace(crunchifyLine.charAt(c))) {
        spaceNum++;
    } else {
        restOfTheTextTogether++;
    }
}
```

The other way to go about this would be simply to take:

```
restOfTheTextTogether = crunchifyLine.length() -
    UppeLetter /*[sic]*/ - LowerLetter - spaceNum;
```

Also for style, you're mixing variables starting with lowercase and those starting with uppercase, which you can see [the automatic syntax highlighter](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) marks as meaning different things generally (even though that's just convention).

Answer (score 1):

Not an elegant solution, but still it will work for you :

```
final int SPACE_ASCII = ' ';
    final int UPPER_CASE_LOWER_ASCII_LIMIT = 'A';
    final int UPPER_CASE_UPPER_ASCII_LIMIT = 'Z';
    final int LOWER_CASE_LOWER_ASCII_LIMIT = 'a';
    final int LOWER_CASE_UPPER_ASCII_LIMIT = 'z';
    final int DIGIT_LOWER_ASCII_LIMIT = '0';
    final int DIGIT_UPPER_ASCII_LIMIT = '9';
    final String OTHER_CHARS = "\". ' ()/ :;";

    int uppercaseCount = 0;
    int lowercaseCount = 0;
    int whitespaceCount = 0;
    int otherSymbolsCount = 0;
    int discardedSymbolsCount = 0;

    String text = "$Your String Goes here. 123#";

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        Character c = text.charAt(i);
        if (c == SPACE_ASCII) {
            whitespaceCount++;
        } else if ((c >= DIGIT_LOWER_ASCII_LIMIT && c <= DIGIT_UPPER_ASCII_LIMIT)
                || OTHER_CHARS.contains(String.valueOf(c))) {
            otherSymbolsCount++;
        } else if (c >= UPPER_CASE_LOWER_ASCII_LIMIT && c <= UPPER_CASE_UPPER_ASCII_LIMIT) {
            uppercaseCount++;
        } else if (c >= LOWER_CASE_LOWER_ASCII_LIMIT && c <= LOWER_CASE_UPPER_ASCII_LIMIT) {
            lowercaseCount++;
        } else {
            discardedSymbolsCount++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("White Space : " + whitespaceCount);
    System.out.println("Upper Case : " + uppercaseCount);
    System.out.println("Lower Case : " + lowercaseCount);
    System.out.println("Others : " + otherSymbolsCount);
    System.out.println("Discarded : " + discardedSymbolsCount);
```